# c recursive binary

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-tree, prefix-tree

I understand the "rules" of inserting

```
void printTree(BTNode* node) {
    
    if (node == NULL)
        return;
    printTree(node->left);
    printf("%c", node->item);
    printTree(node->right);

}
```

Comment: The signature of createExpTree is wrong. To parse a prefix expression, you need to know where the left operand **ends** before you start parsing the right operand. Your function doesn't report back the final position of the cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `createExp`, the right node may be build with some chars already parsed by the left node. It will happened each time the left node parses more than one char.

To prevent this, `createExp` should return an info to where parsing ends. Something like this :

```
char *createExpTree(BTNode** root, char* prefix)
{

    if (*prefix) {

       if (!isdigit(*prefix)) {
            *root = malloc(sizeof(BTNode));
            (*root)->item = *prefix;
            (*root)->left = NULL;
            (*root)->right = NULL;

        }
        else {
            *root = malloc(sizeof(BTNode));
            (*root)->item = *prefix;
            (*root)->left = NULL;
            (*root)->right = NULL;
            return prefix;
        }
    }

    prefix = createExpTree(&(*root)->left, ++prefix);
    return createExpTree(&(*root)->right, ++prefix);
}
```

If you need to keep `createExpTree` signature, you can flatten the recursion into an loop like that :

```
void createExpTree(BTNode** root, char* prefix)
{
    BTNode** stack[SIZE];
    int stackPosition = 0;

    while (*prefix) {
        *root = malloc(sizeof(BTNode));
        (*root)->left = NULL;
        (*root)->right = NULL;
        if (isdigit(*prefix)) {
            (*root)->item = *prefix++;
            if (stackPosition == 0) break;
            root = stack[--stackPosition];
        }
        else {
            (*root)->item = *prefix++;
            stack[stackPosition++] = &(*root)->right;
            root = &(*root)->left;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. However the signature should not be changed, hence I can't do it your style unfortunately. Do you have any suggestions to do this without changing the signature?

Comment: You could make the `prefix` variable global, and pass a dummy second parameter to the `createExpTree` function to keep the same signature. But many, including me, will see it as a **dirty** solution...

Comment: The solution is probably to flatten the recursivity into a loop.

Comment: Do you have any hints for me? I switched to recursion because I couldn't do it iteratively. I added Stack Struct to the original post that I may use to help me build the tree

Comment: Fortunately you have a number digit limitation (200), so you may not need a struct to use a stack and a simple array may be sufficient.